# How can I migrate flow information from a local SQLite database to a PostgreSQL database in Prefect 2.14?

Tags: database-migration, perfect

I'm using Prefect 2.14 to manage my workflow, and currently, the flow meta information is stored in a local SQLite database. I want to migrate this information to a more reliable PostgreSQL database integrated with Prefect.

I've duplicated the local SQLite database into a PostgreSQL database, and the Prefect server is now connected to the PostgreSQL database. However, when I start the Prefect server, I encounter an error message saying 'relation "flow" already exists'.

How can I correctly migrate the flow information without encountering this error?

I droped the alembic_version table, making perfect server connet to postgre database without error saying "Can't locate revision identified by '2dbcec43c857'"